# wxMenu connect events

Tags: events, wxwidgets

```
wxMenuBar * menubar = m_frame->GetMenuBar();
wxMenu * menu = menubar->GetMenu(1);
wxInt32 menuId = menu->FindItem(wxT("MENU"));    
wxMenuItem * menuItem = menu->FindItem(menuId); 
wxMenu * steps = menuItem->GetSubMenu();
steps->Connect(wxEVT_COMMAND_MENU_SELECTED, wxCommandEventHandler(Class::OnMENU), NULL, this);
```

This is the code but when I click on the menu, OnMENU is not triggered. Is this right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK command events, such as menu events, are sent to the parent window, which in this case is `m_frame`. You need to call `Connect()` on `m_frame`, not on the menu (item).

Comment: It is preferable to use `Bind()` over `Connect()` in the newer (since 2.9.0) versions of wxWidgets. There are several advantages to `Bind()` including the ability to dynamically `Unbind()` but possibly the most useful is that many common errors will be flagged at compile time rather than run time for `Connect()`.